# Need help optimizing a join

Tags: mysql, optimization, join

Can anyone help me optimize this query? It takes 15 seconds. If I move the WHERE clauses up to the join itself, still the same result.

```
SELECT
`users`.`employeeID` as `username`,
`users`.`firstName` as `fname`,
`users`.`lastName` as `lname`
FROM `enrollment`
INNER JOIN `users` ON `enrollment`.`employeeID` = `users`.`employeeID`
WHERE `enrollment`.`number` = [int]
AND
`enrollment`.`term` = [int]
AND
(
`enrollment`.`status` = 'E'
OR
`enrollment`.`status` = 'M'
)
ORDER BY    
`users`.`lastName` ASC,
`users`.`firstName` ASC;
```

Takes as long as this:

```
SELECT
`users`.`employeeID` as `username`,
`users`.`firstName` as `fname`,
`users`.`lastName` as `lname`
FROM `enrollment`
INNER JOIN
`users` ON `enrollment`.`employeeID` = `users`.`employeeID`
AND
`enrollment`.`number` = [int]
AND
`enrollment`.`term` = [int]
AND
(
`enrollment`.`status` = 'E'
OR
`enrollment`.`status` = 'M'
)
ORDER BY    
`users`.`lastName` ASC,
`users`.`firstName` ASC;
```

This is the EXPLAIN results

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  users   ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    52925   Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  enrollment  ref employeeID,number_term  employeeID  9   ezlrn.users.employeeID  2   Using where
```

Comment: Please show us your `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: I agree with njk.  Stick "EXPLAIN" in front of your select statement, run it, and post your results.  The SQL looks fine (I prefer the first one), it sounds like you may need some indices.

Comment: updated with EXPLAIN. First time using the site, unfamiliar with formatting. Will try to get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer exhaustively we would need to check out the query plan, which you obtain issuing an `EXPLAIN SELECT...(your query)`, and the index structure already in place.

In the hypothesis that you have no indexes yet (except maybe the `PRIMARY KEY` ones), and that is the problem, let's see how to whip up something (possibly further improveable):

```
SELECT
    `users`.`employeeID` as `username`,
    `users`.`firstName` as `fname`,
    `users`.`lastName` as `lname`
FROM `enrollment`
    INNER JOIN `users` ON `enrollment`.`employeeID` = `users`.`employeeID`
WHERE `enrollment`.`number` = [int]
    AND
    `enrollment`.`term` = [int]
    AND
    (
        `enrollment`.`status` = 'E'
    OR
    `enrollment`.`status` = 'M'
    )
    ORDER BY    
        `users`.`lastName` ASC,
        `users`.`firstName` ASC;
```

You have a `JOIN` clause beetween `enrollment.employeeID` and `users.employeeID`.

So the first couple of indexes you need is right there:

```
-- CREATE INDEX enrollment_ndx ON enrollment(employeeID); -- wait on this one
CREATE INDEX users_ndx ON users(employeeID);
```

Then the `WHERE` clause contains some more conditions that can be usefully indexed. So the final index for `enrollment` would be:

```
CREATE INDEX enrollment_ndx ON enrollment(employeeID, number, term, status);
```

Try creating the indexes on enrollment and users, and try again (posting the query plan).

Note: you can also use the syntax `enrollment.status IN ('M', 'E')` in your query to simplify it.

Comment: Perfect, Iserni, Thank you. down to milliseconds for query :)

Answer (score 0):

You need an index on the `enrollment` table containing (at least some of) `number`, `term`, and `status`.  You will also need an `employeeID` index on `employees` (if it isn't already the primary key, which it should be).

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON enrollment (number, term, status);
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON users (employeeID); // if needed
```

This will make sure mysql uses the index to look up in the `enrollment` table first and join to the `users` table second.